# Swiping a SlidingPaneLayout inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slidingpanelayout

I'm trying to use a SlidingPaneLayout inside of a ViewPager. All I can find are solutions for the other way around, like [Using Android's SlidingPaneLayout with ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490899/using-androids-slidingpanelayout-with-viewpager) which doesn't work.

Is there something easy to change to allow the SlidingPaneLayout's edge to get priority over a ViewPager's? I don't know anything about handling touch events or I'd try to tackle it myself.

Answer (score 0):

JFeinstein slideMenu project is referred to in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026373/sliding-menu-gesture-overwrites-the-scrollable-gesture-of-a-graph-gesture-androi) - very similar to yours. The config for the inner view can be configured to consume the swipe from the edge of the bezel, before that event propogates to the ViewPager

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't quite the same thing. SlidingPaneLayout doesn't offer an option like that, it tries to eat touch events for it's entire space just like ViewPager does.